# Can Josephus avoid killing his countrymen in the Josephus problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, computer-science

In the [Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem), there are $n$ people in a circle, and every kth person is killed going around the circle. I'll add that any $j$th person who is killed is killed by the ($j + 1$)th person. The last two people standing survive. For $n = 41$, are there any values of $k$ so that Josephus, who is either the last or the second-to-last survivor, could have avoided killing anyone? What about if $n \gt 2$ can be chosen freely?

For $k = 1$, the last survivor can avoid killing anyone if he doesn't kill the second-to-last survivor. For $n = 3$, the last survivor can avoid killing anyone, but I think the second-to-last survivor can't.

---

Background you don't need to read:

This problem is named after a story given by Josephus. Here is the story from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem):

> However, in this extreme distress, he [Josephus] was not destitute of his usual sagacity; but trusting himself to the providence of God, he put his life into hazard [in the manner following]: "And now," said he, "since it is resolved among you that you will die, come on, let us commit our mutual deaths to determination by lot. He whom the lot falls to first, let him be killed by him that hath the second lot, and thus fortune shall make its progress through us all; nor shall any of us perish by his own right hand, for it would be unfair if, when the rest are gone, somebody should repent and save himself." This proposal appeared to them to be very just; and when he had prevailed with them to determine this matter by lots, he drew one of the lots for himself also. He who had the first lot laid his neck bare to him that had the next, as supposing that the general would die among them immediately; for they thought death, if Josephus might but die with them, was sweeter than life; yet was he with another left to the last, whether we must say it happened so by chance, or whether by the providence of God. And as he was very desirous neither to be condemned by the lot, nor, if he had been left to the last, to imbrue his right hand in the blood of his countrymen, he persuaded him to trust his fidelity to him, and to live as well as himself.

From the story, it seems that Josephus does not kill any of his countrymen and does not want to. So while watching [Numberphile's explanation of the Josephus problem](https://youtu.be/uCsD3ZGzMgE?t=680), I was dismayed to see that with $n = 41$ and $k = 2$, both the last and second-to-last survivor (positions 19 and 35) end up murdering several people.

It's not entirely clear from the story whether this actually follows the procedure in the Josephus problem. It seems that the men do not have a fixed order, as when only he and another man are remaining, it is apparently indeterminate whether he or the other man would have to kill the other based on the lots. But assume that the story does follow the Josephus problem, with $n = 41$ and some unknown $k$. Say that the men are arranged in order clockwise around the circle, all men are facing inward, the killing happens clockwise as well, and a man is killed by the man to his left-hand side (the man following him in the lot number order). (From Josephus's description above, it looks like the first, $(k + 1)$th, $(2k + 1)$th, etc. people are killed, rather than every $k$th, although I don't think this indexing matters for my problem here.)

Are there any values of $k$ for which Josephus, who is either the last or the second-to-last survivor, does not end up being a murderer? If not, what if we can freely choose n ($n \gt 3$) as well? (For $n = 3$, we can have $k = 3$.) I guess Josephus and the last survivor must be directly next to each other at the start. When is this possible? If it is not possible, perhaps that provides evidence that the Josephus problem is incompatible with Josephus's description of his predicament here.